# Passar código gerado javaScript para outra pagina dentro da tag <script>

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Tenho duas funções uma prepara os dados e faz um call para o Ajax e dentro da chamada para o Ajax tem um callback para outra função. Conforme código abaixo:

```
function retorno_pizza_nacionalidade(result){
console.log(result);
}

function grafico_pizza_nacionalidade(){
var dados = "typepost=grafico_pizza_nacionalidade";

AjaxExecute("php/main_index.php", dados, retorno_pizza_nacionalidade, erro);
}
```

Isso tudo funciona perfeitamente, o problema é que preciso passar o retorno da função retorno_pizza_nacionalidade para dentro da tag  que fica na minha página index.php como posso fazer isso com javascript ou JQuery. Pesquisei bastante, mas não encontrei nada do tipo. Abaixo o retorno que preciso "colar" dentro da tag . Desde já obrigado.

```
$(function () {
            Highcharts.chart('pie', {
                chart: {
                    plotBackgroundColor: null,
                    plotBorderWidth: null,
                    plotShadow: false,
                    type: 'pie'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Frequência Nacionalidade'
                },
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    pie: {
                        allowPointSelect: true,
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                            style: {
                                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Brands',
                    colorByPoint: true,
                    data: [{name:'Afeganistão', y:50.00},{name:'Brasil', 
       y:50.00}]
                }]
            });
        });
```

Comment: O segundo código é o retorno da requisição AJAX ou você precisa inserir esse código no retorno da mesma?

Comment: O segundo código é o retorno da requisição Ajax no caso isso foi o que eu coloquei para o console.log(result) printar.

Comment: Não é mais fácil só retornar os dados e construir o gráfico na `index` mesmo?

Comment: Então ele só constrói o gráfico (essa é a função desse retorno) se o código estiver dentro da tag <script>. Eu até poderia colocar dentro do índex mas como eu printaria isso dentro da tag script para que funcione?

Comment: Consegui fazer o código ser inserido na página usando um append do jquery e dando um id para minha tag <script>, o problema é que a página não está interpretando o código que foi adicionado na página. ele aparece lá, mas é como se não existisse. no caso se eu copio o código e coloco no meu documento html funciona perfeitamente. Detalhe eu tive que colocar no echo do php para que o código js não fosse interpretado. echo htmlspecialchars($return);